# Basic Java Issue

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner, public

I have compiled with no errors, however I can complete the first loop no issues. However second go around it will prompt for Division name however the prompt for Number of employees does to. So I end up seeing Enter Division Name: Enter Number of Employees:

Not sure why this is happening, but I don't see anything out of place when looking.

If you see where I went wrong could you point to the line number or string of code.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayRoll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        int employees;
        double salary;        

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Enter Division Name: ");
            name = input.nextLine();

            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
                break;
            }else {
                System.out.print("Enter Number of Employees: ");
                employees = input.nextInt();

                while(employees <= 0) {
                    System.out.print("Number of Employees Must be Greater than 0, Please Re-enter: ");
                    employees = input.nextInt();                
                }

                System.out.print("Enter Average Salary: ");
                salary = input.nextDouble();

                 while(salary <= 0) {
                    System.out.print("Average Salary Must be Greater than 0, Please Re-enter: ");
                    salary = input.nextDouble();
                }

                Division d = new Division(name,employees,salary);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Division " + d.getName());
                System.out.println("Has " + d.getEmployees() + " Employees.");
                System.out.printf("Averaging $%.2f\n",d.getSalary(),"per Employee");
                System.out.printf("Making the Division total: $%.2f\n", d.getTotal());
                System.out.println();
            }                    
        }
    }
}

class Division {
    private String name;  
    private int employees;
    private double salary;              

    public Division(String name, int employees, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.employees = employees;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
       return employees*salary;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public int getEmployees() {
      return employees;
   }

   public void setEmployees(int employees) {
       this.employees = employees;
   }

   public double getSalary() {
       return salary;
   }

   public void setSalary(double salary) {
       this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the StackTrace..?

Comment: @AmiteshRai - the OP says there is no error

Comment: @Ascalonian indeed. I just misread the question

Comment: Step through it with the debugger.

Comment: The question is really "why is it NOT prompting for Division after the first iter?"

Comment: If you used a debugger, you will see that name becomes `""` after the first loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while(true) {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
 }
```

Instantiate your `Scanner` instance `input` in while loop.

Answer (score 1):

just add **input.nextLine();** after every ***input.nextInt();*** OR ***input. nextDouble();*** AS:

```
while(true) {
    System.out.print("Enter Division Name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
         break;
    }else {
         System.out.print("Enter Number of Employees: ");
         employees = input.nextInt();
         input.nextLine();  // Add it Here

        while(employees <= 0) {
             System.out.print("Number of Employees Must be Greater than 0, Please Re-enter: ");
             employees = input.nextInt();    
             input.nextLine();            
        }

         System.out.print("Enter Average Salary: ");
         salary = input.nextDouble();
         input.nextLine();

         while(salary <= 0) {
              System.out.print("Average Salary Must be Greater than 0, Please Re-enter: ");
              salary = input.nextDouble();
              input.nextLine();
         }
         // Rest of the Code
 }
```

To understand why you need to do this , Read Java Documentation

Comment: Not an Effective solution

Answer (score 0):

create a counter variable out of the while loop. let's say counter == 0, increment it at the end of the loop so you won't create a problem in the initial loop using my solution.

```
 int counter = 0;
 While(){   
   System.out.print("Enter Division Name: ");
   if(counter != 0){
    input.nextLine();
   } 
   name = input.nextLine();
   counter++;
 }
```

Comment: This stalls the first loop through. User has to hit enter twice for Division Name. But this works for all the other loops

Comment: @Ascalonian just fixed it by creating a counter. thank-you for pointing that out